# How pyudev is LGPL license but libudev-dev is GPL license?

Tags: udev, pyudev, libudev

The systemd source indicating udev is GPL license:

```
systemd$ vim LICENSES/README.md
The following exceptions apply:

 * some udev sources under src/udev/ are licensed under **GPL-2.0-or-later**, so the
   udev binaries as a whole are also distributed under **GPL-2.0-or-later**.
```

While the corresponding python package pyudev is LGPL license:
https://pypi.org/project/pyudev/

Any idea is more then welcome